# ViewPager with 5 pictures 768x1024 causes OutOfMemory

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory, drawable

I need all 5 images to be on 5 different pages, but 2nd causes out of memory.
here's my adapter :

```
public class InfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter   {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private static final int[] ids = { R.drawable.easter1, R.drawable.easter2, R.drawable.easter3, R.drawable.easter4,
            R.drawable.easter5 };
    Context context;


    public InfoAdapter(Context context)  {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context=context;
        }
```

So, ids[] - is an array of R.id's

and here's getView :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Drawable drawable=context.getResources().getDrawable(ids[position]);
        if (position!=2){
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_item, null);
        }
        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoImage)).setImageDrawable(drawable);


        return convertView;
    }
        else {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_map, null);
                ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoImage)).setImageDrawable(drawable);
                ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.map_area)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
            }


            return convertView;



}
```

How can I avoid outOFMemory and make it work?

Error :

```
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2007)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:673)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at ru.nikeabooks.eastermessage.InfoAdapter.getView(InfoAdapter.java:65)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow.obtainView(ViewFlow.java:785)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow.makeAndAddView(ViewFlow.java:779)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow.postViewSwitched(ViewFlow.java:724)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow.access$7(ViewFlow.java:705)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at org.taptwo.android.widget.ViewFlow$2.run(ViewFlow.java:539)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 18:57:16.557: E/AndroidRuntime(14817):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
```

so the error line is :

```
Drawable drawable=context.getResources().getDrawable(ids[position]);
```

Comment: is your screen so large that you have to put all those images in memory all at once?

Comment: it's a ViewPager. I put not all the Images, only it's ids, which is int[], as far as I understand, it holds only 3 images - current, previous and next. they are jpegs 180kb size only . So why should there be an OutOfMemory exception?

Comment: because you are confusing file size and image size. Images in memory are stored as byte arrays, and an image such as yours takes : 1024*768*4 bytes, ~3Mb

Comment: so ,then, what can I do? no full-screen images?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).  and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html). Your going to have to scale both bitmaps down and display samples because there is no way to display all the images of that size at one time.

EDIT: Try this code and tell me what you get.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

           if (position!=2)
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_item, null);
           else {
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_map, null);
           ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.map_area)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            holder.info_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
           holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(ids[position]);
        holder.info_image.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        return convertView;
    }
}

private static class Holder {
public ImageView info_image;
}
```

Comment: but I changed them to jpegs, 180 kb each - that is not much! I got error at   Drawable drawable=context.getResources().getDrawable(ids[position]);

Comment: Can you be specific as to what is the error you are getting?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at ru.nikeabooks.eastermessage.InfoAdapter.getView

Comment: so it crashes at getView

Comment: The only way it would crash at getView is if one of the layouts that is getting inflated doesnt have one of the specified views. Can you post your layout files?